# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate3

I have two table Student and Address.I am using hibernate 3 annotation for here.

## My Student class

```
package net.viralpatel.contact.form;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    private long studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private Address studentAddress;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String studentName, Address studentAddress) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    public long getStudentId() {
        return this.studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getStudentName() {
        return this.studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Address getStudentAddress() {
        return this.studentAddress;
    }

    public void setStudentAddress(Address studentAddress) {
        this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
    }

}
```

## Address class

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    private long addressId;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipcode;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(String street, String city, String state, String zipcode) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    public long getAddressId() {
        return this.addressId;
    }

    public void setAddressId(long addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_STREET", nullable = false, length=250)
    public String getStreet() {
        return this.street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_CITY", nullable = false, length=50)
    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_STATE", nullable = false, length=50)
    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ZIPCODE", nullable = false, length=10)
    public String getZipcode() {
        return this.zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

}
```

## Hibernate Config File

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact" />
        <mapping class="net.viralpatel.contact.form.Student" />
        <mapping class="net.viralpatel.contact.form.Address" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

## I got the error

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'student0_.studentAddress_ADDRESS_ID' in 'field list'

Anybody know what is the exact issue

help is highly appreciated,
Thanks,
Shihab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does your address class look like? It seems from the error that your address object is not having an address_id field. Check your database if it contains an address_id.

Comment: yes my address object has address_id field and my address table has ADDRESS_ID field. I added the address class above

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, i added my hibernate config file too above